# Alternating between AVSpeechSynthesis and AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, avspeechsynthesizer

I have an application that goes back and forth between speaking (using `AVSpeechSynthesizer`) and listening (using `AVAudioSession`).

If I allow the speaking to stop naturally (the end of its phrase), and then start listening, everything works well. But if I allow the user to interrupt the speaking, then after (exactly!) 4 interruptions in a row, the speech sythnesizer will stop with the error `Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O`.

Here are my `AVSpeechSynthesizer` methods:

```
func speakMessage(theMessage: String) {
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: theMessage)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
    utterance.rate = 0.52

    synth.speak(utterance)
}

func stopSpeaking() {
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    if synth.isSpeaking {
        synth.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")
        synth.speak(utterance)
        synth.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
    }
}
```

Here is the `AVAudioSession` method, up to the point where the error occurs:

```
private func startRecording() throws {

    // Cancel the previous task if it's running.
    if let recognitionTask = recognitionTask {
        recognitionTask.cancel()
        self.recognitionTask = nil
    }

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
    try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

    recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    ...
```

I assume the call `try audioSession.setActive(true ..` is where the error happens - AVAudioSession first tries to deactivate, but the docs say

> Deactivating your session will fail if any associated audio objects
>   (such as queues, converters, players, or recorders) are currently
>   running

How can I safely deactivate the audio session, when the user interrupts speech synthesis?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue today and after experimenting a bit, I found out that pausing the synthesizer before stopping it allows to deactivate the audio session without errors. So, this is how my `stopSpeaking()` method looks like:

```
var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

....

func stopSpeaking() {
    synthesizer.pauseSpeaking(at: .immediate)
    synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
}
```

BTW, the error only occurs if `stopSpeaking(at:)` is called with `.immediate` boundary. If the method gets `.word` as an argument, at least in my case, deactivating the audio session doesn't cause an error.

Comment: I can confirm that Natalia's answer still works and is needed.  The trouble with using .word as the argument, is that you can run into difficulty if you are relying on notifications that speech has stopped - it can take a long time to stop speaking and thus you can get an "unexpected" notification that speech has stopped.  So the pause/stop solution is the best of two bad alternatives.